# Android rating bar only show one star

Tags: android, xml, interface, rating

I am using Android default rating bar, but on some devices (Samsung), it only shows one star as you see in the photos. I don't know what is causing this issue and how to resolve it. Appreciate your help.

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:max="5"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Comment: your rating bar has no problem, this maybe because of your style or dialog

Comment: It happens only sometimes on samsung devices

Comment: same. do you have a solution?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? We have a few users reporting the same issue, primarily on Samsung devices running Android 9. Haven't been able to reproduce it myself on any of my test devices (including an S8), so I am wondering if it is correlated with a system setting or theme that only certain users have enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Found it! I was able to reproduce this issue on a Samsung device running Android 9 after enabling `Settings -> Advanced features -> Video enhancer`, and fixed it by disabling hardware acceleration on all RatingBars as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel):

```
ratingBar.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

Comment: Just amazing! This helped. How did you know?